# Having problem with a multilevel-array in Twig

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, twig

I trying everything but I don't know how to get a day that is associated with a vacation object. In a multi-dimensional array in a Twig template I put a year, the year has 12 months, and every month has days, every day has a name("Monday,..") and has vacations, vacations has a vacation object. I m trying to  show for every day who has a vacation.
My controller code:

```
$calendar['year'] = $year;

        for ($month = 1; $month <= 12; $month++) {
            $monthData = [];

            $numberOfDaysInThisMonth = Carbon::createFromDate($year, $month)->daysInMonth;

            // nafilat sve dane po keyevima
            for ($day = 1; $day <= $numberOfDaysInThisMonth; $day++) {
                $monthData[$day] = [
                    'day' => Carbon::createFromDate($year, $month, $day)->dayName
                ];

            foreach ($vacations as $vacation) {
                if((int)$vacation->getRequestedDate()->format('d') === $day  and (int)$vacation->getRequestedDate()->format('m') === $month){
                    $monthData[$day]['vacations'] []= $vacation;
                    }
                }
            }

            $calendar['months'][$month]['days'] = $monthData;

        }
```

Twig template

```
{{  calendar.year }}
{% for key, months in calendar.months %}
    <table style="width:100%">
        <tr><h4>{{key}}</h4></tr>
        <th>
    {% for key, days in months %}

        {% for key, day in days %}
            {{ day.day }}
            {% if vacations  %}
                {% for vacation in vacations %}
                {{ vacation.requestedBy.firstName }}
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}

            {% endfor %}

        {% endfor %}

        </th>
    </table>
    {% endfor %}
```

**In the template I trying to get a vacation name from the user who has that day a vacation but I get for every day in a year all the users who are on vacation**

**On the web I get this output where for every day I get every vacations user name**

[image]

**The array looks like this :** 
[image]

Comment: whats the expected output?  Also `vacation` is undefined, prolly u'r doing `day.vacations`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem. Now the output is for every month I show every day and if the day has a vacation then I show every user name for that day.

```
{{  calendar.year }}
{% for key1, months in calendar.months %}
    <table style="width:100%">
        <tr><h4>{{key1}}</h4></tr>
        <th>
    {% for key2, days in months %}

        {% for key3, day in days %}
            <tr>
                {{ key3 }}{{ day.day }}
                {% for vacation in vacations %}
                    {% if key3 == vacation.requestedDate|date('d') and key1 == vacation.requestedDate|date('m')%}
                    {{ vacation.requestedBy.firstName }}
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}

        {% endfor %}

        </th>
    </table>
    {% endfor %}
```